# Mercurial Adding 60+ Merges Randomly

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge, tortoisehg

I just had the strangest thing happen to my mercurial repository, I'm genuinely worried for it's integrity.

### Background

I have been committing/pushing intermittently all day no problem until just now where a single commit/push combo yielded a warning that I'd be pushing new branches to the remote location. I whipped open TortoiseHg to see just exactly was going on in my repo tree that would be causing this. (Perhaps i accidentally commited from `tip:-1`.

After opening tortoiseHg I was presented with this:

[image: Merge Central]

Naturally I'm alarmed by this, note the dates these merges are happening from, weeks and months ago. I tracked the lines all the way back to the source to find that they're originating from pretty-much everywhere in my history where merges have happened (and a couple other spots).

[image: Origins]

### Questions

- What **could have** caused this?
- Is there some hg command/feature that does this intentionally or am I most likely looking at a bug?
- Is there a simple way to fix this without re-cloning my repo from my remote host?

I am genuinely caught off guard with this one. I most certantly did not perform 60+ merges today, I'm baffled.

### Extra Information

TortoiseHG: 2.0.5 (Merc 1.8.4)
OS: Windows7

Comment: Two questions:  1) What version of TortoiseHg?  2) Does the command-line (maybe `hg outgoing`) give the same result?  You may be better off contacting the TortoiseHg and/or Mercurial mail lists with this one.

Comment: That graph doesn't say you did them today. It says you did them 6 weeks ago on the most recent.

Comment: @Tim Henigan: Updated the Body with some more Info. I was able to undo this nasty with the MQ Extension's "Strip" command. Still would like to know WHY this happened. I dont want it to happen again >_>

Comment: Ummmmm. Is this a subrepo? How could this have happened without your notice?

Comment: @Joel B Fant: I know, but they are at the tip. That's why I'm confused, further down is my "today" commits (where that long line on the left from the working directory is going) Tortoise-HG shows commits by Revision #, so that doesn't neccesarily mean they're in the same commit-date order.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: It's not a sub-repo, It's a normal repository, and that's exactly what I'd like to know, how could this happen without me knowing. (And in the blink of an eye)

Comment: `hg glog` shows the same? Do you have some exotic extensions enabled?

Comment: @Oben Sonne: I assume you meant `hg log` and yes it shows the same. All I have enabled is MQ.

Comment: @Aren, no, I meant [`glog`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GraphlogExtension), a variant of `log` with revision graph illustrations.

Answer (score 2):

It is a pity you cannot see the dates of your commits 762:795, but I guess they are spread over the same period of 4 months as 1509:1539. Also, it would be interesting to see who were authors of all these csets (both of them)

From the look of 762:795 I would guess you are 2 developers coordinating, since you have these small merges every 5 commits or so. The long range of merges could come from a third repository you have set up for continuous integration (i.e. automated build), which were not in your normal repository, but which you pulled by accident, just prior to making the 1509:1539 snapshot. This third repository could hold some tiny change far far back in time, which caused all these merges to occur, every time you pushed to the third repository.

If you want to get rid of csets, cloning with -r is the cleanest way to do it. MQ strip is very handy, especially if you use TortoiseHg, but also a bit more dangerous.

I very much doubt that Mercurial would do a thing like this behind your back, but if you need more assistance you can get immediate help at IRC freenode.net. For a web client, go to http://webchat.freenode.net. The Mercurial wiki has some [background information about IRC](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/IRC).

Comment: Our CI Pulls from our central repo with a readonly account, but otherwise you've guessed everything else pretty spot on. The other developer on this project is away (just had a baby) and I didn't pull.  I ended up using strip as this hadn't made it's way into the remote. The date-ranges DO match up with the commits at the end of their tails. I wonder if this was a data corruption thing when a commit happened. I've often wondered what the implications of constantly upgrading our HG/TortoiseHG. Is it possible that could be the cause?

Comment: I guess this is a little too late, as you have already done a strip, but if you look at cset 1465 you will find one or more csets in your CI that is not in your central repo. Note that this is not data corruption, but simply the csets in your CI repository which you will normally not see.

Comment: Both Mercurial and TortoiseHg are careful to not destroy your repository content. Updating the programs should not cause any trouble. If in doubt, use hg verify to validate your repository internal structure.

Comment: speaking only for myself, i tend to screw up and do something stupid, leading to results i cannot later understand without a lot of pain, much more often than i find bugs in widely used third party software.  you may be a much better man than me....

Comment: One more thing: The GTK version of TortoiseHg has a feature called "compact graph", which would show the merges in your first screenshot as one column, instead of a fan of 31 columns. This feature has not yet been ported to the Qt version as per version 2.1 due to lack of demand from users.